# PL/SQL Macro, like in C Programming

Tags: oracle, plsql, macros

So i've been studying C programming about Macros and using them, but in my job i'm using PL/SQL a lot and I was wondering if there is some way to do the same type of thing in PL/SQL.  Right now I have it calling a function with 3 different values and then returning a value but the function is so simple that I think I could do it from inside of the original stored procedure. In C a Macro is a line (or lines) of code that just get completely replaced by the call upon compilation, but it is way more efficient than calling a function over and over.

Example from C:

```
#define query(fieldValue, Attribute, Table) (select fieldValue from Table where record = Attribute)
```

and when called in the body of the code, query(value, value, value) would get completely replaced by the select statement.

just a rough example, of how it might appear in C because i'm really not sure how it would be in PL/SQL.

Is this possible in SQL? It would have to be for 2-3 lines of code, thats it.

Thanks a lot,
   SMKS

Comment: No, it is not possible. create a cursor or function.

Comment: I already have it in function form, but it gets very inefficient I think when the function is called like 30 times from the same procedure. And a cursor wouldn't work because I would have to change the sql statement everytime and it would just get messy.  So there is no more efficient way to do it?

Comment: You could use dynamic sql, that would take some reading.

Comment: You may want to read about the `INLINE` pragma. "The `INLINE` pragma specifys that a subprogram call is, or is not, to be inlined. Inlining replaces a subprogram call (to a subprogram in the same program unit) with a copy of the called subprogram."

Comment: Simply put, there is no macro processor in PL/SQL. I recommend that you not worry about this until you've got a provable performance issue. Remember the prayer of St. Von Neumann - rest thine head, close thine eyes, take a deep breath, and **Believe** in the power of Moore's Law. Amen. :-)

Comment: dose this help ? https://today.java.net/node/219423/atom/feed

Comment: No it doesn't at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just following on from OldProgrammer's comments, I think you would want a single function that uses dynamic SQL to return single values from very similar SQL statements.

Below is an example of how this can be acheived:

```
declare 

  function get_field_val(
      p_field          varchar2,
      p_table          varchar2,
      p_where_clause   varchar2
  )   return varchar2 is
      v_query     clob;
      v_result    varchar2(4000);
  begin

      v_query := 'select to_char(' || p_field ||')' ||
                 'from ' || p_table || ' ' || p_where_clause;                 

      execute immediate v_query into v_result;

      return v_result;

  end;

begin

  dbms_output.put_line(
      get_field_val(
          p_field        => 'COLUMN_NAME',
          p_table        => 'ALL_TAB_COLUMNS',
          p_where_clause => 'where owner = ''SYS'' and table_name = ''ACCESS$''
              and column_id = 1'));

  dbms_output.put_line(
      get_field_val(
          p_field        => 'max(table_name)',
          p_table        => 'all_tables',
          p_where_clause => 'where owner = ''SYS'''));

end;
```

A few things to note about this:

1. This function can only return a single varchar value. If you want different types or arrays of values you'll need to approach this using built-in or user defined plsql collections.
2. It's probably a bad idea to make this kind of function public as it means anyone could run any query with the same privledges as the package definer (unless you create it with  AUTHID CURRENT_USER)

Comment: Thank you for this answer by the way! The use of dynamic sqltook me a while to figure out but it's very useful.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the original question. Yes it helps the OP, but doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to use macros in most any language, but it does require an extra step. 
The [m4 macroprocessor](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) can be used as a pre-processor.

There are quite a few resources available for m4, just google for m4 macro processor.

Here is a simple PL/SQL example

Following is the macro file.

The m4_discard and m4_undiscard code is not strictly necessary, it serves to reduce whitespace in the output.

`'define(`m4_discard', `define(`m4_undiscard', `divert'(divnum))divert(-1)')dnl"
m4_discard

```
define(`pl_sleep',`dbms_lock.sleep($1);')
define(`noop',`null;')
define(`useless_loop',
`for i in 1..$1
 loop
   $2($3)
end loop;')
m4_undiscard
```

Following is the PL/SQL file test.m4sql

```
include(./macros)

useless_loop(`10',`pl_sleep',`.1')

useless_loop(`10',`noop',`.1')
```

Now for some PL/SQL pre-processing

```
    >  m4 test.m4sql





   for i in 1..10
   loop
      dbms_lock.sleep(.1);
   end loop;


   for i in 1..10
   loop
      null;
   end loop;
```

There is still more white space than I would like, but you can see how m4 might be used.

Whether or not you use this depends on how badly you want to use macros.

As stated in other answers, dynamic SQL may be the answer.

At times dynamic SQL may work well, but for some uses, such as dynamic block of PL/SQL, it is a coding nightmare.

My intent is to use m4 on a current PL/SQL project where I need some logging code at the beginning and end of each procedure. This use is not really a good fit for dynamic SQL in my opinion, and m4 only needs to be used once to retrofit the code with the calls as they need to be.

Comment: You cannot imagine how your answer helps me! Many thanks for the inspiration.